# Problems with LDAP authentication: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, class, javafx, ldap

I've got a class that allows me to authenticate with **LDAP**. When i run this code in a project with just one class (for testing reasons) i don't have problems and it returns a boolean value, as is expected, but when i run it in the project i'm working in, i got the following error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter does not implement the requested interface org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilter
```

This is the method the allows me to authenticate:

```
public static void autenticarUsuario(String usuar, String password) throws LdapException, CursorException{       

    Dn user = Dn.EMPTY_DN;
    try{
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    LdapConnectionConfig config = new LdapConnectionConfig();
    config.setLdapHost(SERVER_IP);
    config.setLdapPort(PORT);
    config.setName("uid=ldapsearch,ou=System,ou=Users,dc=fiec,dc=espol,dc=edu,dc=ec");
    config.setCredentials(CREDENTIALS);        
    conn = new LdapNetworkConnection(config);
    }catch(Exception e){            
    }
    String s1 = usuar;
    String s2 = password;

    //System.out.println("Nombre: "+s1+"  Contra: "+s2);
    try {
        conn.bind();
        System.out.println(conn.isAuthenticated());            
        // Create the SearchRequest object
        SearchRequest req = new SearchRequestImpl();
        req.setScope( SearchScope.SUBTREE );
        req.addAttributes( "*" );
        req.setTimeLimit( 0 );
        req.setBase( new Dn( "ou=Users,dc=fiec,dc=espol,dc=edu,dc=ec" ) );
        req.setFilter( "(uid="+ s1 +")" );

        // Process the request
        SearchCursor searchCursor = conn.search( req );

        while ( searchCursor.next() )
        {
            Response r = searchCursor.get();
            if(r instanceof SearchResultEntry){
                Entry re = ((SearchResultEntry) r).getEntry();
                user = re.getDn();
            }
        }

        conn.bind(user, s2);
        //return(conn.isAuthenticated());
        inLDAP = conn.isAuthenticated();             
    } catch (InvalidConnectionException ex) {
        //System.out.println(ex);
    }        
    catch (LdapException e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CursorException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();        
     }
    inLDAP = false; 
}
```

The project i'm working in is a **JAVAFX** application, but this method is called in a class that doesn't extend from application (just java code to verify user credentials).

This is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter does not implement the requested interface org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilter
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.register(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:267)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.addLast(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChainBuilder.buildFilterChain(DefaultIoFilterChainBuilder.java:436)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.addNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:528)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.handleNewSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:501)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1116)
at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

These are the libraries i'm working:

```
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.cursor.CursorException;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.cursor.SearchCursor;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Entry;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.Response;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.SearchRequest;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.SearchRequestImpl;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.SearchResultEntry;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.SearchScope;
import org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.name.Dn;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapConnection;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapConnectionConfig;
import org.apache.mina.*;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection;
import org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.exception.InvalidConnectionException;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
```

I don't know why this is happening, i'll appreciate any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is a version problem.  Between Mina 1.0 and Mina 2.0, they moved the `IoFilter` interface (among other things) from `org.apache.mina.filterchain` to `org.apache.mina.core.filterchain`.  I think you are trying to use code compiled for Mina 2.0 with the Mina 1.0 implementation.

Solution: examine your build and runtime classpaths and dependencies to figure out how this happened ... and fix the inconsistency.